# How to duplicate string until another string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a text file that is structure like below :

```
 293.0                             2305.3     1508.0                         
                                   2466.3     1493.0                         
                                   2669.5     1578.6                         
                                   3497.2     1768.9                         
                                   4265.5     2092.4                         
                                   5940.8     2558.6                         
                                   7308.7     3015.4                         
                                   9377.7     3814.6                         
 295.0                             2331.4     1498.1                         
                                   3617.0     1893.2
```

I'm still new in Linux, is there anyway for it to be output as desire like an example below :

```
 293.0                             2305.3     1508.0                         
 293.0                             2466.3     1493.0                         
 293.0                             2669.5     1578.6                         
 293.0                             3497.2     1768.9                         
 293.0                             4265.5     2092.4                         
 293.0                             5940.8     2558.6                         
 293.0                             7308.7     3015.4                         
 293.0                             9377.7     3814.6                         
 295.0                             2331.4     1498.1                         
 295.0                             3617.0     1893.2
```

So basically, I want it to duplicate until it meets another variable.

Comment: Should be easy to do in `awk`. Save the first field in a variable. If the current row only has 2 fields, print the variable followed by the fields in the row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: Does the number of spaces between the column matters?

Comment: the number of spaces doesn't matter

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Barmar's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124128/how-to-duplicate-string-until-another-string-in-bash/49124290#comment85253302_49124128):

If row contains three columns, save first column to a variable and print all three columns. If row contains two columns, print variable and column one and two:

```
awk 'NF==3{c=$1; print $1,$2,$3}; NF==2{print c,$1,$2}' file
```

Output:

```
293.0 2305.3 1508.0
293.0 2466.3 1493.0
293.0 2669.5 1578.6
293.0 3497.2 1768.9
293.0 4265.5 2092.4
293.0 5940.8 2558.6
293.0 7308.7 3015.4
293.0 9377.7 3814.6
295.0 2331.4 1498.1
295.0 3617.0 1893.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command:

```
$ sed 's/ \+/|/g' dupl.in | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{if($1){buff=$1; printf "%.1f ", buff;} else {printf "%.1f ", buff;} printf "%1.f %1.f \n",$2, $3}'                                                                                                                                   
293.0 2305 1508 
293.0 2466 1493 
293.0 2670 1579 
293.0 3497 1769 
293.0 4266 2092 
293.0 5941 2559 
293.0 7309 3015 
293.0 9378 3815 
295.0 2331 1498 
295.0 3617 1893
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pure bash  style thanks to its array capacities:

```
$ while read -a f; do \
if [ ! -z ${f[2]} ]; then \
c=${f[0]}; echo ${f[@]}; \
else \
echo $c ${f[@]}; \
fi; \
done <file
```

I have cut lines for reading purpose.

Line by line (while read), I save fields in an array "f". If the third field is not null (if [ ! -z...]), I save first column and print all fields, else, I print c and the 2 other fields.